# Is there a better way to match these boolean dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare whether a row in two different columns will have a string in it or not. I have the answer, and this code works... But it's a bit ridiculous and I know I'm being an amateur. Here it is:

In:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['y', '','z','','d','e'], 'b': ['x','', '','c','','g']})
df_boolean = df.notna()

df_boolean['doublematch'] = (df_boolean['a'] == True) & (df_boolean['b'] == True)

match_list = []
for bool in df_boolean['doublematch']:
    if bool == True:
        match_list.append('Match')
    else:
        match_list.append(None)
```

In the end, I would like to have a single column, that has 4 data categories:

1. A double Match
2. No Match
3. Single Match (a)
4. Singe Match (b)

I think this is the best way to count each match and create metrics on how the dataset is matching.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by a "match"; is it just a non-null value? [Also `''` is **notnull** with respect to pandas, perhaps you mean to use `None` or `np.NaN`]

Comment: Yea the value doesn't really matter... It's moreso creating indicators that signify whether there's a string in 1 column (on column a or b), both, or none.

Comment: You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and write your own function to compare the rows and return the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and write your own function to compare the rows and return the value.

Something like this.

```
import pandas as PD

df = PD.DataFrame({'a': ['y', '','z','','d','e'], 'b': ['x','', '','c','','g']})

def check(row):
    if bool(row["a"]) and bool(row["b"]):
        return 0
    elif bool(row["a"]) and not bool(row["b"]):
        return 1
    elif not bool(row["a"]) and bool(row["b"]):
        return 2
    elif not bool(row["a"]) and not bool(row["b"]):
        return 3

df["match"] = df.apply(check, axis=1)
```

Here I return a different integer (from 0 to 3) to represent the different matches, but you can return whatever you think is best. The final `df` is:

```
   a  b  match
0  y  x      0
1            3
2  z         1
3     c      2
4  d         1
5  e  g      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering no_match values are empty strings, you can use the following code to create your categories.

```
df_bool = df.replace("", float('nan')).notna()

df.loc[df_bool['A'] & df_bool['B'], 'cat'] = "double_match"
df.loc[df_bool['A'] & ~df_bool['B'], 'cat'] = "match_a"
df.loc[~df_bool['A'] & df_bool['B'], 'cat'] = "match_b"
df.loc[~df_bool['A'] & ~df_bool['B'], 'cat'] = "no_match"
```